# Accessing model from razor view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code in controller and razor view.

When `Upload()` is called I want to return another view with the model as the parameter so it's accessible within the view.

But I keep getting *"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"* on `@Model.PhoneNumber`

Another question is that does the model has to be strongly typed? It seems when I pass in `new { PhoneNumber = "123456" }` the property can't be accessed from view either.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{code}/CertificateValidation")]
public ActionResult CertificateValidation()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection file)
{
    return View("CertificateValidation", new IndexViewModel { PhoneNumber = "123456" });
}
```

View:

```
model WebApplicationMVC.Models.IndexViewModel    
<p>@Model.PhoneNumber </p>
```

Comment: "Another question is that does the model has to be strongly typed?" That is still strong typing; it's just that the compiler creates the type rather than you creating the type. The problem with that approach is what do you put in this part of the view: `@model XXXXXX`? You didn't name the type, so you can't put anything there.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your get Method.

Your following method does not return any model. So Model is null so it gives error.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{code}/CertificateValidation")]
public ActionResult CertificateValidation()
{
    var model = new IndexViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are returning the view with the model is correct and should not have any issue.

```
return View("CertificateValidation", new IndexViewModel { PhoneNumber = "123456" });
```

That said, most probably your actual code would not be like this and might be fetching data from some source like a database probable, which could be returning `null` which you can investigate by debugging or writing null checks.

For the second answer, if you are specifying the type of the model in the view with the `@model` directive, you have to provide an instance of this type in the return View() method call. Alternatively you can use the `@model dynamic` which would allow you to pass anything as the model. [See this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views)